# Using a dynamic URL to add a picture with XSL:FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to add an image to my PDF output. The problem ist, that

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('URL here')"/>
```

will accept nothing but an URL. The link to the image I want to add however is derived from another value inside the XML document being transformed.

Is there any way to generate image URL dynamiclly?

Thanks in advance
sebastian

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840326/set-a-image-url-dynamically-into-a-xsl-file

Answer (score 5):

Use [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-attribute-value-template)

> An attribute value template consists
>   of an alternating sequence of fixed
>   parts and variable parts. A variable
>   part consists of an XPath expression
>   enclosed in curly brackets ({}). A
>   fixed part may contain any characters,
>   except that a left curly bracket must
>   be written as {{ and a right curly
>   bracket must be written as }}.

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840326/set-a-image-url-dynamically-into-a-xsl-file/3912335#3912335